# Запуск сторонних .exe без сохранения на диск

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть четыре *.exe* файла
Я делаю *winforms* приложение с четырмя кнопками. При нажатии на кнопку запускается один из четырех *.exe* файлов.

Сложность в том, что *.exe* файлы должны быть внутри программы.
Как вариант - мы добавим файлы в ресурсы программы и при компиляции получим приложение единым файлом с вшитыми внутри файлами *.exe*.

Необходимо научиться, при нажатии одной из четырех кнопок, запускать соответствующий ей *.exe* файл. Вообщем использовать *.exe* прям из ресурсов программы.

К сожалению, вариант копирования из ресурсов файла в темповую папку и запускать этот файл не вариант. Нельзя давать доступ к этим *.exe* файлам.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Это непростая задача, можете посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory). В любом случае, это не обезопасит от получения доступа к exe. Можно снять дамп запущенного процесса, поправить адреса точки входа/таблицы импорта - и получить нужный exe практически в изначальном виде.

Comment: @kmv если они в ресурсах в оригинальном виде - даже запускать ничего не надо будет, выдираются EXE оттуда на раз.

Comment: А эти 4 exe — .net или нативные?

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, у меня не получилось запустить из ресурсов
Можешь подскажите код, если вы уверены в своих словах на 100%

Comment: VladD ммм, .exe файлы это продукт работы другого приложения

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, слона-то я и не приметил)

Comment: @МаксимСажин какой код? Вытаскивания EXE из ресурсов? Я его руками в HIEW вырежу за 2 минуты.

Comment: да) я уже понял о чём вы
может подскажите варианты
я понимаю что захочешь .net переломаешь полностью
но хотелось бы в конечной папке проекта видеть один файл с програмкой))

Comment: Как, наверное, вы уже поняли, от продвинутых хакеров вы всё равно не спасётесь. Поэтому просто положите все четыре экзешника в папку вашего приложения и напрямую вызывайте их. А чтобы их не видели простые юзвери, навесьте на них атрибуты скрытый и системный. Визуально в Проводнике при настройках по умолчанию будет один файл.

Comment: Как вариант... но бредово, файл с программой 1мб весящий, а папка весит 1гб))

М, есть еще идеи?)
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: А если я потом файл с проектом защищу с помощью электроного ключа?) Guardant мне доступен, тогда тоже на изи вытащите ресурсы?

Comment: @МаксимСажин если ресурсы - как два пальца. Ресурсы не шифруются.

Comment: а можно как то файлы ресурса засунуть в один файл, его зашифровать, какой нить тип непонятный
и через программу запускать его

Answer (score 1):

Решением является написание собственного загрузчика: выделяете память, раскладываете в нее секции вашего файла, настраиваете (если надо) импорты и передаете управление на точку входа.

Comment: нету примеров? так на словах мне сложно понять, что делать((

Comment: @МаксимСажин есть примеры, в троянах, в пакерах. Если вы не представляете что такое VirtualAlloc, какой формат EXE-файлов - у вас не получится все равно.

Answer (score 1):

Антивирусники взбесятся от подобных решений. Скажу что задача не из простых.

Прийдется потанцевать с kernel32.dll и ntdll.dll. 
Когда-то делал такое. Но увы разработка под Windows давно в прошлом.

Если бы приложения были ваши, можно было организовать их в виде DLL файла и вызывать из основной программы. Но в любом случае если их кто-то захочет оттуда достать их достанут

Comment: что значит разработка под windows в прошлом?)
я думал над тем чтобы засунуть .exe в dll но как я понял это в корне неверная затея))

Comment: Из программирования осталось только PHP, и везде (дома, на работе, и т.д. Linux). Исходники тоже форматнулись, поэтому таки в прошлом. Да затея плохая как по мне. 
Вы хотите продавать чужие программы?)

Comment: я не понимаю вас вообще))
приложения же надо писать, программки разные
Нет, не чужие))

Comment: Вы надумали чего то лишнего))
Мне дали 4 .exe файла(каждый можно запустить, что то происходит)
сказали чтобы я сделал винформу с 4 кнопками, нажав на которые будут запускаться .exe
И конечным результатом должен быть один файл проекта winforms запускающий .exe
сами .exe созданы людьми, попросившие решить меня эту задачу

Comment: Отходим от темы))

P.S. Вам системное программирование приносит значительную прибыль? Это крайне узкая специализация как по мне, по сравнению с перспективными Web и Mobile направлениями. Может в будущем еще выстрелит что-то связанное с VR. Скоро большинство приложений будет в облаках

Comment: Тогда пусть эти люди дадут вам исходники этих программ, и вы сделаете одно multiform приложение с 5-тю формами)

Comment: Да ну. Слухи о смерти десктопа сильно преувеличены.

Comment: в данный момент надо решить эту проблему
или предложить другие варианты
конечно можно просто засунуть .exe файлы рядом с проектом))
слушайте, а как в играх поступают?
можно ли как нибудь извратить файл, к примеру переименовать в .dat1, а из программы запустить напрямую по файлу, я пробовал но  не получилось)

Comment: Могу конечно поставить виртуальную машину с Windows и попробовать восстановить функционал. На какой версии Windows будут использовать? Сколько ваши знакомые люди, готовы за это решение отблагодарить?

Comment: win 7x64
да в конторку я одну попал, опыта мало но держусь
Дали эту задачу, вот пытаюсь решить
Всё, что не найду, говорится о невозможности решения этой задачи
Мб так и скажу главному

Comment: @МаксимСажин задача определенно решается через написание собственного загрузчика.